# crm developer tools integrated in visualstudio

Tags: msbuild, dynamics-crm-4

I'm trying to get crm-explorer and developer tools integrated and running within visual studio

I suceeded in having the crm explorer integrated, but don t know how to simple build 
I read about devbuild but when triggering it from a visualstudio command line I get:

> c:\Projects\MyCrmSolution>ECHO OFF
>   Welcome to the Developer Build
>   Starting Build soluton files Microsoft
>   (R)-Buildmodul, Version 3.5.30729.1
>   [Microsoft .NET Framework, Version
>   2.0.50727.3620] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. Alle
>   Rechte vorbehalten.
>
> Das Erstellen wurde am 06.06.2011
>   10:39:30 gestartet. Projekt
>   "c:\Projects\MyCrmSolution\BuildScripts\tfsbuild.proj"
>   auf Knoten 0 (Standardziele).
>   c:\Projects\MyCrmSolution\BuildScripts\tfsbuild.proj
>   : error MSB4057: Das Projekt enthält
>   kein DesktopBuild-Ziel. Die Erstellung
>   von Projekt
>   "c:\Projects\MyCrmSolution\BuildScripts\tfsbuild.proj"
>   ist abgeschlossen (Standardziele) --
>   FEHLER.
>
> Fehler beim Erstellen.
>
> "c:\Projects\MyCrmSolution\BuildScripts\tfsbuild.proj"
>   (Standardziel) (1) ->
>   c:\Projects\MyCrmSolution\BuildScripts\tfsbuild.proj
>   : error MSB4057: Das Projekt enthält
>   kein DesktopBuild-Ziel.
>
> ```
> 0 Warnung(en)
> 1 Fehler
> ```
>
> Vergangene Zeit 00:00:00.06

straight tips would be nice

Comment: I'm assuming you meant to use the German edition, but unfortunately I can't read German.

Comment: o.k. i18n -> The project has no DesktopBuild Target

Comment: Thanks, can you please give the English version of the text that you typed into the VS command prompt to trigger the build?

Comment: o.k. that was just : DevBuild.bat

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, it sounds to me like the build script is unable to find the desktop build target file.  I would open up the build script that you are executing first and look for external scripts that it references.  My guess is that one of these references will be missing or named differently.  That is what I would investigate first.

Comment: thx Do you mean things like this: "   <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v9.0\TeamTest\Microsoft.TeamTest.targets" /> " which is in the TFSbuild.proj from the BuildScripts\BuildTypes\DevBuild

Comment: more detailed: The first DevBuild.bat is in the project directory. In this there is referenced: MSBUILD BuildScripts\tfsbuild.proj /p:SkipGetLatest=true" and so - in my thinking it references to the directory BuildScripts where it finds TFSBuild.proj with : "<Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\BuildTypes\$(BuildDefinition)\TFSBuild.proj"/>" and so comes to BuildTypes\DevBuild where another TFSBuild.proj is , and there for example I did note the directory of the crm server , which is in our case not localhost , and this worked .

Comment: Not sure if you said that fixed your issue but those files are all chained together like you have put.  If your issue is not fixed I would just keep walking the chain of files.

Comment: No it is not fixed , I just described the 'chain of files' how you call it and it ends with a build error: C:\Projects\MyCrmSolution\BuildScripts\tfsbuild.proj : error MSB4057: Das Projekt enthält kein DesktopBuild-Ziel. // the project has no desktop build target

Comment: I'm not sure without seeing it, one option would be to post the different high level build scripts until you get to the DesktopBuild one and maybe we'll be able to find a missing reference.

Comment: thx for answering : I just followed the steps there:http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/E2DevTkt/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2485 and took the "Customizing CRM with the CRM DevToolkit" documentation there. then tried to check the server which is in our case not localhost and the crm-explorer works integrated in visualstudio. He finds entities for example . I agree that some references may probably be wrong. thats what I suppose. So at the end of the tfsbuild.proj the code is : "   
  <PropertyGroup> <MarkerFolder>$(SolutionRoot)\BuildScripts\Outputs\DevBuild\Markers\</MarkerFolder>

Comment: <CrmOrganizationName>CRMCONFIG</CrmOrganizationName>
    <CrmServiceAddress>http://SERVER03//msCrmservices/2007/Crmservice.asmx</CrmServiceAddress>
    <CrmServiceServer>SERVER03</CrmServiceServer>
    <CrmServiceProtocol>http://</CrmServiceProtocol>
    <CrmServiceImportTimeout>300000</CrmServiceImportTimeout>
    <CrmServicePublishTimeout>300000</CrmServicePublishTimeout>
    <CRM_SVC_TIMEOUT>5000</CRM_SVC_TIMEOUT>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="Overrides.targets" />
  <Import Project="EnvironmentConfig.targets" />

Comment: <Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Configuration\Configuration.CRM4.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Configuration\Configuration.Website.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Configuration\Configuration.Database.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Configuration\Configuration.properties" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\bin\UKDynamics.MSBuildTasks.CRM4.tasks" />

Comment: <Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\bin\Microsoft.Sdc.Common.tasks" /> <PropertyGroup>
    <RootDirectory>C:\</RootDirectory>
    <ProgramFiles>$(RootDirectory)Program Files</ProgramFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>   "  <- which means 'SERVER03' is my testcrm place

Comment: sorry for the formatting. this board don't allows new lines and sets a limit at 600 characters , I can post it again // more straightforward sliced in adequate pieces // if wanted.